# MomentJS Accounting for Timestamp's DST and not current DST

Tags: javascript, datetime, timestamp, momentjs, moment-timezone

I am using momentjs to account for timezone differences in an international application. I use it to parse ISO 8601 (ex. '2021-12-17T18:40:02.389Z') strings, and expect that the date and time be local to the client. I am running into an issue where it displays both CST and CDT, for example, in the application. It seems to be using the timezone/daylight savings of the timestamp, rather than converting it to the timezone we are currently in. For example, it's December as of this posting, so I would like all times to be displayed by moment in CDT, whereas in May, I would like it to be displayed in CST, regardless of when the timestamp was created. Is this possible with moment? I haven't been able to find out about this in their docs.

Comment: What you're asking for make no sense to me. If you want to see what the local time was in your current time zone, at the instant represented by the given timestamp, then why would you apply the *current* offset rather than the one observed at the time of the timestamp? Surely it makes more sense to say "If you were in the same geographical location back when the timestamp occurred, the local time would have been X". I'm finding it really hard to imagine *any* use case for what you're asking for.

Comment: (I mean, you *could* find the current offset from UTC and apply it to the UTC timestamp given, but that wouldn't give you a *useful* value in my opinion.)

Comment: (Note that "converting it to the timezone we are currently in" shows a bit of a misunderstanding - your time zone doesn't change over time unless you move or there are political upheavals. The UTC offset observed by the time zone changes over time.)

Comment: @JonSkeet—unfortunately the term "timezone" has more than one meaning and it's often (incorrectly and confusingly) treated as a synonym for "offset". I think it takes more than a couple of comments to clarify. Even articles like [this](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/07/06/time-zones-offsets/) that try to explain the difference get it wrong. :-)

Comment: '2021-12-17T18:40:02.389Z' is a UTC timestamp, it represents a single moment in time that doesn't change to be "local to the client". What can change is the local representation of the same moment in time if the place has an offset other than +0 (zero). E.g. 2021-12-17T14:40:02.389-04:00 and 2021-12-18T00:10:02.389+05:30 both represent the same moment in time but with different offsets. It doesn't make any sense to display a date and time using a location's DST offset for a date and time when DST wasn't being observed in that location.